Getting NullPointerException while writing Integration TestCases in Junit 5 with mockMvc
Getting this NPE even when all services are annotated
Here is the code, and I think I can also get similar error for EncryptDecryptService though not getting that for now
Error
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "comservice.service.SearchService.searchPatient(com.service.requests.SearchPatientRequest)" because "this.patientSearchService" is null
    at com.service.Controller.SearchControllerIntegrationTest.testSearchPatients(SearchControllerIntegrationTest.java:72)

Controller class
RestController
@Slf4j
public class SearchController {
    
    @Autowired
    SearchServiceImpl SearchService;
    @Autowired
    SearchService psService;
    
    @Autowired
    private EncryptDecryptService encryptDecryptService;
    
    @GetMapping("/search")
    public ResponseEntity<SearchResponse> searchPatients(SearchPatientRequest message) {
        
        return new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
}

If I m commenting when.thenReturn and verify statement then mockmvc is giving NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION
TestCases

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(SearchController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SearchControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    SearchServiceImpl patientSearchService;

    @MockBean
    private EncryptDecryptService encryptDecryptService;

    @InjectMocks
    private SearchController patientSearchController;

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

  
}

pom versions
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mockito Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mockito JUnit Jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

Not able to figure out what is missing or wrong
I want these test cases to run via mvn clean test command
Updated Code: Still not working

@WebMvcTest(PatientSearchController.class)
public class TestPatientSearchControllerIntegration {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private SearchService pss;
    @MockBean
    private SearchServiceImpl patientSearchService;

    @MockBean
    private EncryptDecryptService encryptDecryptService;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

   
    private Patient CreateORGStudentInElastic() {
      .....
    }
}


It was Surefire Plugin issue for me, please keep the latest vesrion or which is compatible with your dependencies, I changed it from 2.. to 3.2.5

org.apache.maven.plugins
maven-surefire-plugin
3.2.5

I believe you are mixing a few different concepts together ultimately causing it to not do as you expected. Let me break it down into each observation:
You are using the MockitoExtension with WebMvcTest and AutoConfigureMockMvc. WebMvcTest (depending on your Spring version) includes AutoConfigureMockMvc so you don't need to include that. Also Spring does a lot of things for you internally which allows you to no longer need to use the MockitoExtension directly so I would first start out and remove that annotation.
Secondly, in your test, @InjectMocks is used but ultimately you are just calling the service directly. It doesn't appear you are even using your patientSearchController in your test so I would remove it as it is only needed in the reference in the WebMvcTest annotation. If you do need to use it later on, you should annotate it with a @Autowired or @SpyBean if you need to modify any method calls instead.
Third, you shouldn't need a @BeforeEach setup method in your current use case as everything should be setup for your through WebMvcTest. Also ObjectMapper is provided by Spring so unless you want just a pure new one, you can just use it by adding the @Autowired annotation.
Fourth, I don't see patientSearchService wired in your controller code so you will need to ensure that is available either through @Autowired annotation or through a constructor with the field as a final (if you are using Lombok, the @RequiredArgsConstructor is helpful).
After cleaning up the above, you will either have a successful run or new messages that should guide you to a successful run.

I changed everything as you mentioned, Updated new test class, But still not working, I m getting another issue that in my main controller class, I m autowiring both service interface as well as serviceImpl class of same interface, because via serviceImpl we are accesing constructor and via interface I m accessing method searchPatient(SearchPatientRequest pss)
This is causing another issue, I m not getting which one to autowire or which one to @mockBean, if I m not mocking serviceImpl class then it is giving error that consider defining a bean SearchServiceImpl  in your code.

@Kinova Thats realy strange of injecting implementation and interface in controller. You should use @Qualifier then

@Alex where will Qualifier exactly use in test class?

@Kinova you should qualifiers in your controller an test

@Alex I tried not worked still getting NPE

@Kinova can you share your entire pom file? And can you share you most up to date controller code?

@AnthonyLofton I resolved it, it was surefire plugin version issue, Thanks for your efforts

@Kinova good deal. Also if you are using the Spring Boot parent, most of the compatible versions are included in your Pom directly which allows you to not need to specify any specific versions in the Pom so you shouldn’t even need to specify the surefire version.
